# Cookies - Cross Domain User Tracking

Tags: php, cookies, analytics, tracking

#### My question

Is it posible to make a PHP script there make a cookie there track the user on the internet so when they come back you can see the domains he/she have visit. the other domains are not owned by me, that why I ask.

the best will be a code example, but I can use everything to help with this

---

#### Why I ask

The reason why I ask is that im working on make a website user can visit to see how much data the internet can take from you, by visit and then come back later and see how much it have learn

all I have found on stack overflow have been people there just talk about it but with not "real" answer

Comment: No, of course that is not possible.

Comment: Think about it. If you could do it everybody could do it which would be the internet hell. Read more about supercookies and services like google analytics / adwords they try such things.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to accomplish cannot be done. In order to track a user on a website that you do not own would be to have either a small tracking pixel or a small snippet of JavaScript that could report back to your website informing you of what website they were on. That's how advertising networks accomplish the data that they do.